# PHP - Creating an array from CSV and then echo the values

Tags: php, csv

I am attempting to parse CSV strings into a multi-dimensional array. I am using the following code to do this...

```
public function exportPartsAuthority($fileArray)
{       

    foreach ($fileArray as $filename => $fileContent) {
        $lines = explode("\n", $fileContent);
        $formatting = explode(",", $lines[0]);
        unset($lines[0]);
        $results = array();
        foreach ( $lines as $line ) {
           $parsedLine = str_getcsv( $line, ',' );
           $result = array();
           foreach ( $formatting as $index => $caption ) {
              if(isset($parsedLine[$index])) {
                 $result[$formatting[$index]] = trim($parsedLine[$index]);
              } else {
                 $result[$formatting[$index]] = '';
              }
           }
           $results[] = $result;
        }

        $var_str = var_export($results, true);
        $var = "<?php\n\n\$$values = $var_str;\n\n?>";
        file_put_contents('/home/apndev/public_html/output.txt', $var);

    }       
}
```

The end result is this:

```
$ = array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'Ordernumber' => '100000002',
    'Orderdate' => '02/10/2013',
    'OrderStatus' => 'pending',
    'PurchasedWebsite' => 'Main Website - Main Website Store - Default Store View',
    'PaymentMethod' => 'checkmo',
    'ShippingMethod' => 'flatrate_flatrate',
    'Subtotal' => '2.0000',
    'ShippingCost' => '10.0000',
    'GrandTotal' => '12.0000',
    'TotalTax' => '0.0000',
    'TotalPaid' => '',
    'TotalRefunded' => '',
    'ItemName' => 'K&N Air Filter Wrap',
    'ItemSKU' => 'YA-6504PK K&N',
    'ItemISBN' => '',
    'ItemStock' => '',
    'ItemPrice' => '1.0000',
    'CostPrice' => '',
    'ItemOrdered' => '1.0000',
    'ItemInvoiced' => '0.0000',
    'ItemSent' => '0.0000',
    'CustomerID' => '1',
    'BillingFirstName' => 'Brian',
    'BillingLastName' => '',
    'BillingCompany' => '',
    'BillingE-Mail' => '',
    'BillingPhone' => '',
    'BillingAddress1' => '',
    'BillingAddress2' => '',
    'BillingCity' => '',
    'BillingPostcode' => '',
    'BillingState' => 'Florida',
    'BillingCountry' => 'US',
    'ShippingFirstName' => 'Brian',
    'ShippingLastName' => '',
    'ShippingCompany' => '',
    'ShippingE-Mail' => '',
    'ShippingPhone' => '',
    'ShippingAddress1' => '',
    'ShippingAddress2' => '',
    'ShippingCity' => '',
    'ShippingPostcode' => '',
    'ShippingState' => 'Florida',
    'ShippingCountry' => 'US',
    'Vendor SKU' => '',
    'Line Code
' => '',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'Ordernumber' => '100000002',
    'Orderdate' => '02/10/2013',
    'OrderStatus' => 'pending',
    'PurchasedWebsite' => 'Main Website - Main Website Store - Default Store View',
    'PaymentMethod' => 'checkmo',
    'ShippingMethod' => 'flatrate_flatrate',
    'Subtotal' => '2.0000',
    'ShippingCost' => '10.0000',
    'GrandTotal' => '12.0000',
    'TotalTax' => '0.0000',
    'TotalPaid' => '',
    'TotalRefunded' => '',
    'ItemName' => 'K&N Air Filter Wrap',
    'ItemSKU' => 'YA-6601-TDK K&N',
    'ItemISBN' => '',
    'ItemStock' => '',
    'ItemPrice' => '1.0000',
    'CostPrice' => '',
    'ItemOrdered' => '1.0000',
    'ItemInvoiced' => '0.0000',
    'ItemSent' => '0.0000',
    'CustomerID' => '1',
    'BillingFirstName' => 'Brian',
    'BillingLastName' => '',
    'BillingCompany' => '',
    'BillingE-Mail' => '',
    'BillingPhone' => '',
    'BillingAddress1' => '',
    'BillingAddress2' => '',
    'BillingCity' => '',
    'BillingPostcode' => '',
    'BillingState' => 'Florida',
    'BillingCountry' => 'US',
    'ShippingFirstName' => 'Brian',
    'ShippingLastName' => '',
    'ShippingCompany' => '',
    'ShippingE-Mail' => '',
    'ShippingPhone' => '',
    'ShippingAddress1' => '',
    'ShippingAddress2' => '',
    'ShippingCity' => '',
    'ShippingPostcode' => '',
    'ShippingState' => 'Florida',
    'ShippingCountry' => 'US',
    'Vendor SKU' => '',
    'Line Code
' => '',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'Ordernumber' => '100000003',
    'Orderdate' => '07/10/2013',
    'OrderStatus' => 'pending',
    'PurchasedWebsite' => 'Main Website - Main Website Store - Default Store View',
    'PaymentMethod' => 'checkmo',
    'ShippingMethod' => 'flatrate_flatrate',
    'Subtotal' => '1716.5000',
    'ShippingCost' => '5.0000',
    'GrandTotal' => '1721.5000',
    'TotalTax' => '0.0000',
    'TotalPaid' => '',
    'TotalRefunded' => '',
    'ItemName' => 'Cardone High Pressure Diesel Injection Oil Pump',
    'ItemSKU' => '2P-225 Cardone',
    'ItemISBN' => '',
    'ItemStock' => '',
    'ItemPrice' => '1716.5019',
    'CostPrice' => '',
    'ItemOrdered' => '1.0000',
    'ItemInvoiced' => '0.0000',
    'ItemSent' => '0.0000',
    'CustomerID' => '1',
    'BillingFirstName' => 'Brian',
    'BillingLastName' => '',
    'BillingCompany' => '',
    'BillingE-Mail' => '',
    'BillingPhone' => '',
    'BillingAddress1' => '',
    'BillingAddress2' => '',
    'BillingCity' => '',
    'BillingPostcode' => '',
    'BillingState' => 'Florida',
    'BillingCountry' => 'US',
    'ShippingFirstName' => 'Brian',
    'ShippingLastName' => '',
    'ShippingCompany' => '',
    'ShippingE-Mail' => '',
    'ShippingPhone' => '',
    'ShippingAddress1' => '',
    'ShippingAddress2' => '',
    'ShippingCity' => '',
    'ShippingPostcode' => '',
    'ShippingState' => 'Florida',
    'ShippingCountry' => 'US',
    'Vendor SKU' => '2P-225',
    'Line Code
' => 'A1',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'Ordernumber' => '',
    'Orderdate' => '',
    'OrderStatus' => '',
    'PurchasedWebsite' => '',
    'PaymentMethod' => '',
    'ShippingMethod' => '',
    'Subtotal' => '',
    'ShippingCost' => '',
    'GrandTotal' => '',
    'TotalTax' => '',
    'TotalPaid' => '',
    'TotalRefunded' => '',
    'ItemName' => '',
    'ItemSKU' => '',
    'ItemISBN' => '',
    'ItemStock' => '',
    'ItemPrice' => '',
    'CostPrice' => '',
    'ItemOrdered' => '',
    'ItemInvoiced' => '',
    'ItemSent' => '',
    'CustomerID' => '',
    'BillingFirstName' => '',
    'BillingLastName' => '',
    'BillingCompany' => '',
    'BillingE-Mail' => '',
    'BillingPhone' => '',
    'BillingAddress1' => '',
    'BillingAddress2' => '',
    'BillingCity' => '',
    'BillingPostcode' => '',
    'BillingState' => '',
    'BillingCountry' => '',
    'ShippingFirstName' => '',
    'ShippingLastName' => '',
    'ShippingCompany' => '',
    'ShippingE-Mail' => '',
    'ShippingPhone' => '',
    'ShippingAddress1' => '',
    'ShippingAddress2' => '',
    'ShippingCity' => '',
    'ShippingPostcode' => '',
    'ShippingState' => '',
    'ShippingCountry' => '',
    'Vendor SKU' => '',
    'Line Code
' => '',
  ),
);
```

When I attempt to echo $results['Vendor SKU'], or var_dump it.. the result is NULL even though I see a value set above. I also notice there is a syntax error at the top ('$ = array').

That being said, I'm ultimately just trying to get the values from the CSV because some of these values will be used to send order information to a third party vendor.

Can anyone point me in the right direction of how to fix my output so that I'll be able to echo the values correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

use the built in php function to parse your csv file rather than re-invent the wheel.

```
str_getcsv
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php

There's a good example on the man page that essentially does what you want:

```
$header = NULL;
    $data = array();
    if (($handle = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== FALSE)
    {
        while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE)
        {
            if(!$header)
                $header = $row;
            else
                $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
    print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple, use the preset CSV reading method:

```
$fp = fopen('data.csv', 'r');

$rows = array();
while (($row = fgetcsv($fp)) !== false)
    $rows[] = $row;

fclose($fp);
```

`$rows` will then contain all data of `data.csv` as a two-dimensional array.

See [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/fgetcsv) for more info.